# How do I add an object to a linked list in alphabetical order in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator, compare, addition

I saw similar questions that included an index in the parameters, but my requirements don't allow me to do that. Assume the array is already sorted in alphabetical order.
This is my first time asking a question so sorry if I did something wrong.

```
public void addElement(Object element){
    LinkedListIterator iterator = new LinkedListIterator();
    int counter = 1;
    int compare = 0;
    if(first == null)
        iterator.add(element);
    else
    {
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            compare = getElement(counter).toString().compareToIgnoreCase(element.toString());
//getElement is a method I made to retrieve an element from the linked list 
//I have tested it and I know it works. Its parameter is an index
//toString() returns a String of what the element is. example: { Fruit } 
//It is in that format with the brackets {}

            if(compare != -1)
                iterator.add(element);
            else
            {
                iterator.next();
                counter++;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Look up insertion sort.

Comment: and beware, `compareToIgnoreCase` not only returns one of -1, 0, 1!

Comment: Hi Brett,
    Can you elaborate your question ?

Comment: Where does `LinkedLIstIterator` come from? It's not part of `java.util`.

Comment: Is `LinkedListIterator` meant to be [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html)?

Comment: Is this a custom LinkedList class or the one in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, I don't know exactly what you're using as a comparison value.  Is it a string value within the object, the name of the object reference, etc?  Assuming that you're inserting an object based on some sort of name variable, this is how you could do it.

Note: I'm sure you can find some sort of existing method/api that does this for you, but I'm assuming you'd like to see how it's done.

For this example, I created a class called AnyObject to iterate and compare.  It looks like this:

**AnyObject class**

```
public class AnyObject {

private String name;
private int num;
private String color;

public AnyObject(String name, int num, String color) {
    this.name = name;
    this.num = num;
    this.color = color;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

}

Using this simple class, we would modify your code so it looks like this:

**AlphaInsertSort Class**

```
import java.util.*;

public class AlphaInsertSort {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<AnyObject> myList = new ArrayList<AnyObject>();
    myList.add(new AnyObject("alphaObj", 44, "blue"));
    myList.add(new AnyObject("betaObj", 7, "orange"));
    myList.add(new AnyObject("gammaObj", 12, "red"));
    myList.add(new AnyObject("omegaObj", 99, "yellow"));
    printList(myList); //helps visualize what's going on
    addElement(new AnyObject("charlieObj", 105, "purple"), myList);
    printList(myList);
    addElement(new AnyObject("aObj", 105, "purple"), myList);
    printList(myList);

    myList.add(new AnyObject("thetaObj", 0, "green"));
    printList(myList);
    addElement(new AnyObject("zetaObj", 2, "pink"), myList);
    printList(myList);
    System.out.println("Finished");
}

public static void addElement(AnyObject element, ArrayList<AnyObject> myList){
    ListIterator<AnyObject> iterator = null;
    //int counter = 1; don't need this
    int compare = 0;
    AnyObject current = myList.get(0); //changed name from first to current and will use this for comparison while iterating
    iterator = myList.listIterator(); //this should set iterator to start of list. There's no constructor for listIterator

    System.out.println("\ncurrent is " + current.toString());

    if(current == null)
        iterator.add(element);
    else
    {

        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            //compare = getElement(counter).toString().compareToIgnoreCase(element.toString());
            compare = current.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(element.toString());

            //for display purposes
            System.out.println(current.toString() + " compared to " + element.toString() + " is " + current.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(element.toString()));

            if(compare > 0) { //want to add element into list if compare is negative. Won't necessarily be -1
                iterator.previous(); //will need to move back a spot before adding. Otherwise will always add element after first encountered element that doesn't come before element inserting
                iterator.add(element);
                break; //make sure to break.  No need to continue iterating
            }
            else
            {
                current = iterator.next();
                //counter++;
            }
        }

        //if element is larger than all existing elements in list
        if(!myList.contains(element)) {
            iterator.add(element);
        }
    } 
}

public static void printList(ArrayList<AnyObject> myList) {
    System.out.println("List contents:");
    for(AnyObject element : myList) {
        System.out.println(element.toString());
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

I removed the counter int because you mentioned in your instructions that you don't have the option to use an index, so there's really no point in including it.  It's also worth noting that compareTo and compareToIgnoreCase don't necessarily return -1 and 1.  It can return any positive and negative values, so changing your conditions would be smart.  Also, compareTo returns a negative number if value that's calling the method is less than the value that it's being compared to, so you want to stop iterating and add the value when compare is negative.  Also, since you don't have iterator that's 1 element ahead of the position you're currently at in your list, you need to move the iterator back 1 element when compare returns a negative integer.  If you don't, your new element will always be added immediately AFTER the first element that comes after it alphabetically.  This is because you can't see the next element immediately after the iterator.  Does this make sense?

For instance, if you have a list of 1, 2, 4, 5, and you want to add 3 to it, you would compare 1 to 3, 2 to 3, then 4 to 3.  When your iterator reaches 2, it doesn't know what the next value is.  Since 3 is larger than 2, it moves on to 4.  4 is less than 3, so add(3) gets called.  However, this places 3 after the element it's being compared to (4).  Your list would then be 1, 2, 4, 3, 5.  The easiest way to fix this is to call iterator.previous(); immediately before iterator.add(3);

Let me know if you'd like further clarification.